# ContentView being Squished by ScrollView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile

While experimenting recenetly I came upon something that I couldn't make sense of. 

I've simplified the code down to its most basic level.
Here is an example of xaml in the page -

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0">
    <ContentView BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="70"/>
    <ContentView BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout x:Name="scroll">

            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentView>
</StackLayout>
```

(In my actual code I am using custom views derived from `<ContentView>`, but the issue remains) 
Note the heightrequest on the first contentview

and here is the code behind

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly int number = 100;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            scrollBoi.Children.Add(new Label() {
                Text = i.ToString(),
                TextColor = Color.White
            });
        }
    }
}
```

It simply adds 100 labels to the `<Stacklayout>` in the `<ScrollView>`

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7d0W.png) is the result on android.

Clearly, the the yellow contentview is not 70px high.

For clarification, if I remove the code in the code behind so no labels are added to the `<StackLayout>`, then [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMRF0.png) is the result. The ContentView has not been squished. I've also found that the more labels I add to the ScrollView, the smaller the ContentView becomes.

Interestingly, the issue does not arise if I use a `<StackLayout>` instead of `<ContentView>`, like so

```
<StackLayout HeightRequest="70" BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
<ContentView BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout x:Name="scroll">

             </StackLayout>
      </ScrollView>
</ContentView>
</StackLayout>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9ORh.png) is the result - and is the desired result. However, I'd like to use a content view, not a stacklayout.
I think there's something odd going on with the contentview but I'm really not sure.

Any explanations or help would be much appreciated,
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1 :**

You could put them in a **Grid** instead of **StackLayout** .

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="70" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentView  Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="70"/>
    <ContentView  Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout x:Name="scroll">

            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentView>
</Grid>
```

**Solution 2:**

Set the property `MinimumHeightRequest`

```
<ContentView  BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="70" MinimumHeightRequest="70" />
```

Comment: Thanks! The grid works great, and it has other benefits I hadn't thought of.